# Transfering mp3 files over a TCP connection. Displaying the download progress using JProgressBar

Tags: file, tcp, transfer, jprogressbar

I am working on a program that sends an mp3 file over a TCP connection. I am trying to use a JProgressBar to show the download progress. However I don't know the file size before fully downloading it. Is there anyway I can get the file size before downloading it from the server side?

Thanks in advance. Here is my code

SERVER:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
dataOut = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
file = new File(LIBRARY, data);
//get length of file
int fileLength = (int)file.length();

fileData = new byte[fileLength];
fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
bis.read(fileData, 0 , fileData.length);
OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
os.write(fileData, 0 , fileData.length);
os.flush();
clientSocket.close();
```

CLIENT:

```
int filesize=999999999; //A TEMPORARY FILE SIZE

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
int bytesRead;
int current = 0;
// localhost for testing
Socket sock = new Socket(SERVER_NAME,DEST_PORT);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
// receive file
byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
out.println(request);
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(request);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
current = bytesRead;
System.out.println(bytesRead);

do {
      bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
      if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
} while(bytesRead > -1);

bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
bos.flush();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(current);
bos.close();
sock.close();
```

Comment: Editing your question to include "SOLVED" and the solution is not how StackOverflow works. Please read the [help] pages, particularly the [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) section.

Comment: Thanks. That's much better. (You can even accept it as correct in a few hours; you won't get reputation for doing so, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:
The solution was not very hard actually. I simply sent the file size before sending the file. So, client receives the file size sets its maximum to file size JProgressBar.setMaximum(fileLength); Then increment the progressbar's value using setValue(); 
Here's my updated code:

SERVER:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

dataOut = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
file = new File(LIBRARY, data);
//get length of file
int fileLength = (int)file.length();

out.println(fileLength);// this sends the file length

fileData = new byte[fileLength];
fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
bis.read(fileData, 0 , fileData.length);
OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
os.write(fileData, 0 , fileData.length);
os.flush();
clientSocket.close();
```

CLIENT:

```
progressBar.setValue(0);
int bytesRead;
int current = 0;
// localhost for testing
Socket sock = new Socket(SERVER_NAME,DEST_PORT);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
// receive file
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));   //CREATE BUFFERED READER TO READ THE FILE SIZE
out.println(request);
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(request);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
int fileLen = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
progressBar.setMaximum(fileLen); // READ THE FILE SIZE
byte [] byteArray  = new byte [fileLen+100]; //SET THE BYTEARRAY 100 BYTES EXTRA
bytesRead = is.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
current = bytesRead;
do {
      bytesRead = is.read(byteArray, current, (byteArray.length-current));
      if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
      progressBar.setValue(current);
} while(bytesRead > -1);

bos.write(byteArray, 0 , current);
bos.flush();
//System.out.println(current);
bos.close();
fos.close();
in.close();
is.close();
sock.close();
```